# Is using `std::shared_ptr` for in/out variables reasonable?

Tags: c++17, shared-ptr, inout

I need some advise regarding usage of `std::shared_ptr` for In/Out parameters. Is having something like

```cpp
std::shared_ptr<Big> expensive_process(std::shared_ptr<Big> foo)
{
    // process foo
    ...
    return foo;
}
```

considered bad practice (as opposed to the usual way of `void expensive_process(Big& foo)`)?. This signature works uniformly (if adopted everywhere) when `foo` is either a local variable or a temporary, e.g. `expensive_process(another_process(foo))` or `expensive_process(foo->clone())`.

### Rationale

I am currently using the following signature when processing data in-place:

```cpp
void process(Big& foo);
```

Changing the signature to `shared_ptr<Big> process(shared_ptr<Big> foo)` has two main benefits:

1. It allows chaining, i.e. `foo = f1(f2(foo))` is valid if `f1` and `f2` both have the same signature.
2. Secondly, it allows working with local and temporary variables uniformly, i.e. `foo = f1(foo)` and `another_foo = f1(foo->clone())` both work.

Neither of these two are possible with the original signature.

Comment: I think it depends entirely on the situation. What made you consider a `shared_ptr` in this case? Why not a  `unique_ptr`? Why a pointer at all?

Comment: @TedLyngmo With `unique_ptr` I need to `std::move` at the call site if its a local variable (which *could* be dangerous, say if the variable is used again). Without pointers, I think I would need two overloads `expensive_process(Big&)` and  `expensive_process(Big&&)` and `std::move(foo)` as return. Although I am not sure if there is a better way of doing it.

Comment: You may need to `std::move` - or you could take it by reference.- perhaps even by `const&`. You can do with one template and perfect forwarding in many cases too. - I think we just have too little information about the problem to be able to give sound advice. The `foo->clone()` business says something but not all. Try making a [mre].

Comment: Thanks so much @TedLyngmo! So the situation is that I have a bunch of functions which mutate some data in-place. Sometimes I need to chain a bunch of them, other times I need to pass a copy of local variable. Chaining is not possible with `void(&)` signature. The argument against local copies is lame: they are just ... kinda annoying! I thought of `shared_ptr(shared_ptr)` b/c it solves both issues.

Comment: Oh I have been away from posting questions for a loooooong time :)

Comment: :-) Got that. Still, you have some open questions from back then with answers. Perhaps they deserve an _accept_?  Anyway, please try to put the necessary information into the question in a way that is easy to read. I have a hard time reading code in comments. A [mre] is always nice.